# Pig : Multiple join statements in single statement

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Please help me getting this done in pig

```
Input: 
record1: ("Ammit", 123, 234, 345)
record2: (map : [
    "123" : ("accountNo": 123, "bank": "ICICI Bank", "branch" : "Delhi"),
    "234" : ("accountNo": 234, "bank": "HDFC Bank", "branch" : "Mumbai"),
    "345" : ("accountNo": 345, "bank": "SBI", "branch" : "Bangalore"),
    ])
```

Above data represents Amit's bank accounts with the details of accountNo, bank and branch. Record1 contains name followed by 3 account number ids, which are ordered (i.e. they represent the order in which Amit opened the account)

```
output: ("Amit", 
    "123" : ("accountNo": 123, "bank": "ICICI Bank", "branch" : "Delhi"),
    "234" : ("accountNo": 234, "bank": "HDFC Bank", "branch" : "Mumbai"),
    "345" : ("accountNo": 345, "bank": "SBI", "branch" : "Bangalore"),
    )
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is probably not possible without a UDF, but if you could post example input and output data, that would help.

Comment: I've given example in the question. Please let me know if its not clear.

Comment: The example is very abstract. Are `record1` and `record2` representing schemas? What are the possible values of `id1`, `id2`, etc. The best way to solve the problem will be to have small text files of input and output, with the goal to write a Pig script that transforms the input into the output.

Comment: Updated the example with actual data. Hope this helps.

Comment: So, this data doesn't look like the kind of format that Pig would use, which might be part of the reason why you're having difficulty with it. What were you planning to use to `LOAD` the data into Pig?

Comment: Also, do you have very large data files? You might be better off not using Pig for this.

Comment: I'm loading the data with AvroStorage(). And yes, I've very large data files, and thus am using Pig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an UDF MapToBag defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12542753/1571865) . That gave me access to values of the maps in record2, which I used to join with ids from record1.

Answer (score 0):

You could flatten the map and then a merge join will maintain the order

https://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigMergeJoin

Comment: I'm not sure how to mention map `key` while writing join statement. IMO, map can be dereferenced using MAPNAME#KEY, where KEY is constant string, but map can not participate in join. Correct me if I'm wrong. I've added the answer, please check and correct if you see anything wrong.